# curl_easy_perform() - do NOT wait for response

Tags: c++, windows, http, curl

#### Background

I have `VS2015 C++` project, running in all `Windows` >= `XP`, that uses [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) to handle the client requests.

#### Problem

Empirically, the server response takes way way too long and my process is blocked.

I'd like to know whether curl offer some method to skip the server response part in the [curl_easy_perform() API](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_perform.html).

#### Attempts

Using [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html) is not a valid option.

I used to [CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) and noticed the following log:

```
[TimeElapsed: 0 ms]:   Trying ...;  
[TimeElapsed: 1 ms]: TCP_NODELAY set;   
[TimeElapsed: 5 ms]: Connected to  () port  (#0);   
[TimeElapsed: 5 ms]: => Send header 
[TimeElapsed: 5 ms]: => Send data   
[TimeElapsed: 6 ms]: upload completely sent off: 493 out of 493 bytes;  
[TimeElapsed: 98 ms]: <= Recv header    
[TimeElapsed: 98 ms]: <= Recv header    
[TimeElapsed: 1753 ms]: <= Recv header  
[TimeElapsed: 1765 ms]: <= Recv header  
[TimeElapsed: 1828 ms]: <= Recv header  
[TimeElapsed: 1887 ms]: <= Recv header  
[TimeElapsed: 1932 ms]: <= Recv data    
[TimeElapsed: 1967 ms]: Connection #0 to host  left intact;
```

You can see that it takes my client tool 6ms to send its data. However, it takes 2 seconds for the server to respond which is so wasteful.

I'd like to "break" the connection/action right after the `upload completely sent off` part.

## Notes

I know I may consider different approaches (which I am) such as:

1. use async curl API
2. use curl in different thread
3. look into the server/client code to find out why is it taking so long

However, the question remains valid.

Comment: You don't care about validating the response HTTP code? What if there is an error?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis That's a valid point I've consider. In the meanwhile, I'm willing to "sacrifices" those users which are a very small portion.

Comment: There is a multi interface for cURL which can simply allow you to handle multiple requests at once. Since you have not explained the use case (if the program servers only a single client or multiple) it is hard to give further advices. If this blocking thing simply prevents you from going on with the next request then the multi interface is what you need. If this is a program that simply serves a single client and then exits and there is another process waiting for it to exit, then multi will not help anyhow. Can you please elaborate on the use scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably use CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION to determine when the upload has been completely sent off, and stop curl then, like

```
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, [](void * , curl_off_t, curl_off_t, curl_off_t ultotal, curl_off_t ulnow) - > int {
  if (ulnow >= ultotal) { /*stop curl, upload is complete*/
    return 1;
  } else { /*upload not complete yet.*/
    return 0;
  }
});
```

(untested)

edit: warning, in order for CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION to be called at all, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS must be set to 0 first, so also do `curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS,0);`

also, did you know that curl is thread-safe? as long as you use `curl_global_init` correctly (eg, run it once in the main thread before any other threads have started using curl functions), the rest of curl_easy can be used in a dedicated thread, that may be even faster for you, as you don't even have to wait for the upload to be complete, just start a dedicated thread for curl

Comment: Condition must be fix from `if (ulnow >= ultotal) ` to `if (ulnow >0 && ulnow >= ultotal) `